# Greater value for year rep than total rep

Tags: bug, reputation-leagues

I was looking at the rep leagues for Interpersonal skills from last year, when I noticed something odd. There are several users on the list whose total reputation is listed as being less than their reputation for the year. It's usually a small amount (less than 50). This makes me think that it's likely that the year rep doesn't take into account rep losses from down voting answers and posting bounties.

However, I came across one where the difference is quite substantial (~1400).

[image]

When I checked the user's profile, I saw that they posted 100 rep worth of bounties and voted less than 30 times, so that wouldn't explain a gap this large. What exactly is going on here?

Comment: Bounties, maybe? Can't check without knowing what account.

Comment: @Catija No, they only posted 100 rep of bounties

Comment: Looks like lots of answers have been downvoted by that user.

Comment: @ShaWiz, they have only voted a total of 28 times

Comment: @Catija [Here](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/18855/ontamu?tab=profile) is their profile if you wanted to look at the account

Comment: They have an answer scoring +125 that's deleted... I wasn't aware of the post @ShaWiz linked to but if that's the case, I guess there's your explanation.

Comment: @Catija actually different case, cache, not private reputation event. (i.e. the rep change was not synced with the leagues.)